# Can't change the default app for opening AVI files

Tags: mediaplayer, devuan, file-associations

I'm using Cinnamon on Devuan ASCII (which is essentially Debian Stretch without systemd).

I'm trying to change the default player for AVI files from Dragon player to Gnome-MPV.

[image]

But - while this seems to be possible, after making the change the default player is *still* Dragon - nothing has happened.

I would try to debug this myself if I'd gotten any kind of an error message, but I don't even have that. What do I do?